# How to iterate over a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a generic menu class that will be used with a 4 line LCD.

I have a specific (non template) version working, but want to extend it to allow the menu to modify a variety of data types (int, float, unsigned...).

Here's the non template version that's working as expected...

```
/*
 * ideally this design allows for defining an arbitrary menu as shown below
 * example...
 * root1
 *    sub1-1
 *    sub1-2
 * root 2
 * root 3
 *   sub3-1
 *   sub3-2
 *     sub3-2-1
 *     sub3-2-2
 *     
 * each node in the menu can be executed, and allow for moving to the next/prev sibling or child/parent
 * this flexibility requires that each node contains pointers to parent, child, and sibling nodes.
 */


class  MenuNode
{
  private:
  char *prompt;
  int value;
  public:
  MenuNode *parent=NULL;
  MenuNode *child=NULL;
  MenuNode *prevSibling=NULL;
  MenuNode *nextSibling=NULL;
  void SetValue(int value)
  {
    this->value = value;
  }
  int GetValue()
  {
    return value;
  }
  char *Prompt()
  {
    return prompt;
  }
  MenuNode(char *prompt, int initialValue, MenuNode *parent, MenuNode *prevSibling)
  {
    Serial.print(prompt);Serial.println(F(" MenuNode"));
    this->prompt = prompt;
    if (prevSibling != NULL)
    {
      this->prevSibling = prevSibling;
      prevSibling->SetNextSibling(this);
      this->parent = prevSibling->parent;
    }
    // prevSibling if provided sets the parent
    if (prevSibling==NULL && parent != NULL) 
    {
      this->parent = parent;
      this->parent->SetChild(this);
    }
    
    value = initialValue;
  }
  void SetChild(MenuNode *child)
  {
    Serial.print(prompt);Serial.println(F(" SetChild"));
    this->child = child;
  }
  void SetNextSibling(MenuNode *nextSibling)
  {
    Serial.print(prompt);Serial.println(F(" SetNextSibling"));
    this->nextSibling = nextSibling;
  }
};
```

Here's some test code that creates the menu structure...

```
// Test menu... 
MenuNode r1("R1",10,NULL,NULL);
MenuNode r2("R2",20,NULL,&r1);
  MenuNode r21("R21",30,&r2,NULL);
  MenuNode r22("R22",40,&r2,&r21); // setting parent is optional, the parent will be set by the prev sibling parent
    MenuNode r221("R221",50,&r22,NULL);
      MenuNode r2211("R2211",60,&r221,NULL);
      MenuNode r2212("R2212",70,NULL,&r2211);
MenuNode r3("R3",30,NULL,&r2);
```

This code iterates over each element printing out the structure

```
void PrintMenuStructure(MenuNode *node,int offset)
{
  while(node != NULL)
  {
    for (int i=0;i<offset;i++)
      Serial.print("-");
    Serial.print(node->Prompt());
    Serial.print(" = ");
    Serial.print(node->Value());
    if (node->parent != NULL)
    {
      Serial.print(" parent=");
      Serial.print(node->parent->Prompt());
    }
    if (node->prevSibling != NULL)
    {
      Serial.print(" prevSib=");
      Serial.print(node->prevSibling->Prompt());
    }
    if (node->nextSibling != NULL)
    {
      Serial.print(" nextSib=");
      Serial.print(node->nextSibling->Prompt());
    }
    if (node->child != NULL)
    {
      Serial.print(" child=");
      Serial.print(node->child->Prompt());
    }
    Serial.println();
    if (node->child != NULL)
      PrintMenuStructure(node->child,++offset);
    node = node->nextSibling;
  }
}
```

This is the output of the previous function demonstrating the structure of the menu...

```
R1 = 10 nextSib=R2
R2 = 20 prevSib=R1 nextSib=R3 child=R21
-R21 = 30 parent=R2 nextSib=R22
-R22 = 40 parent=R2 prevSib=R21 child=R221
--R221 = 50 parent=R22 child=R2211
---R2211 = 60 parent=R221 nextSib=R2212
---R2212 = 70 parent=R221 prevSib=R2211
-R3 = 30 prevSib=R2
```

It all works the way I want, but GetValue/SetValue only operate on int data.

I can create a template version of the class, with the data types of GetValue and SetValue defined by the template parameter, but I don't know now to iterate over the nodes once I do that.

Seems like a simple enough task, but I've been beating my head against the wall for a while, and haven't come up with anything that works. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate over a linked list of classes, but can't figure out how to get a pointer to start iterating.

Sorry, I couldn't get the code formatting to work... :(

Comment: C++ does not have reflection as a language feature. You can't iterate a class's members.

Comment: I thought I presented a fairly straight forward question. This was my first post here, and may be my last. Seems like a lot of folks here are more interested in pointing out whats wrong with a question than trying to understand it and provide something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I interpret your requirement: it seems your should make your

```
int value;
```

a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

That's the lowest cost path.

If you templatize the `MenuNode` class with its `value` type. Then a `MenuNode<int>*` cannot be the parent of a `MenuNode<float*>`, etc. Not without some effort. You'd probably better off make it polymorphic by derivate each type of value your want to support from a common abstract virtual base, and depend on how you want to use the `value`, design your interface.

Comment: Not sure std::variant is available on Arduino. Plain old union (with all its limitations) could be a sensible alternative. A polymorphic class hierarchy with abstract bases and stuff could be useful, but it could also be an overly complicated encoding of the plain old union. It depends on the specific use case.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, I would do it with a union, and add a flag to indicate actual data type, if the only expansion needed are support `int, double, float, std::int64_t`..., etc.

Comment: Since I'm only interested in supporting a few data types  union did the trick for me. @n. m. thanks for taking the time to look this over.